# Java JWT Token Issue

Tags: jwt

I am using JWT token authentication in my application. 
I am generating the token using:

```
Jwts.builder()
                    .setSubject(username)
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, key)
                    .compact();
```

Where "username" is the logged in user. Once the token is created I am verifying the token with every request in my filter using:

```
Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(key)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody()
                .getSubject();
```

The above code returns the username which I compare with the username which I stored in a map during login. 
Now the issue which I notice is that after an idle period when I navigate to another page in the application the comparison fails. 
I compared the Authorization header from my correct request and the request which failed and I see the same token generated in both the request. I am not able to understand where is the issue as the Authorization header for both request looks the same. 
Did anyone faced a similar issue before?

Comment: What is the detail of the issue? Is failing the verification process or is failing the comparison? Seems you are mixing server sessions with JWT. Maybe your session has expired or your cache has been cleaned?

Comment: The logic I added is if the comparison failed then i throw an error to the user with unauthorized access. Application session has not expired because before that click i was able to navigate to the application. With the next request I see this error.

Comment: If the JWT is really present in the header, and it has the `sub` claim as you said, then your "map" has been cleaned in some way. Debug your code. With the code you have posted is not possible to answer your question

Comment: will check and update this thread if I find that as an issue. Thanks.